# Converting date array with getTime()

Tags: javascript, html

this is a snippet of code from a project I am doing, I have to convert dates using to getTime() function and push them into a new array, however everytime i do however the new array prints as NaN, i was hoping to gain some insight on what i was doing wrong and how to fix this issue. Thanks a ton :)

```js
dates = ["28/7/2020", "28/3/2020", "28/1/2020", "28/10/2020"]
// const MAX = dates[0]
//  const MIN = dates[dates.length - 1];
const dateArr = [];
const DAY_IN_MS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000


for (i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
  d = new Date(dates[i])
  dateInMs = d.getTime();
  parseInt(dateInMs);
  console.log(dateInMs);
  dateArr.push(dateInMs);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you able to get dates in other formats?  eg, "d mmm yyyy"?  The issue is the format of the date string - you and I will recognise them as dates, but javascript doesn't.

Comment: try to get a date in `2020-7-28` this pattern rather than `28/7/2020`. So you don't need to spilt your date

Comment: Okay! gotcha, I see exactly what you mean :D Thanks a ton for helping me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to switch the day and month otherwise new Date will return `invalid date`

example:

```
const d = "28/7/2020";
const dateSplit = d.split("/")
new Date(`${dateSplit[1]}/${dateSplit[0]}/${dateSplit[2]}`)
```

will return: `Tue Jul 28 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)`

What you could do is replace your `New date` line with the following:

```
const dateSplit = dates[i].split("/")
const newDate = new Date(`${dateSplit[1]}/${dateSplit[0]}/${dateSplit[2]}`)
d = new Date(newDate)
```

Either that or try to change the initial format to something `new Date` can Handle. This will prevent of having to split and add extra code

EDIT: To get the amount of days between first and last date. Here is an example:

```
const minutes = 1000*60;
const hours = minutes*60;
const days = hours*24;

const date1 = new Date("7/28/2020").getTime();
const date2 = new Date("10/28/2020").getTime();
const dateDiff  = Math.round((date2 - date1)/days);
console.log(dateDiff);
```

EDIT 2: to get the difference in length you would do this (using the dates you mentioned in your comment):

```
const dateArr = [];
let date1 = ("23/9/2020").split("/");
let date2 = ("29/9/2020").split("/");


const diffDays = date2[0] - date1[0];  // date1[0] = 23, date2[0] = 29
for (i = 0; i <= diffDays; i++) {
    // content of the push would save each day between 23 and 29 as value... you can put whatever in here
    dateArr.push(`${date1[0] + i}/9/2020`); 
}
console.log(dateArr.length); // should equal 7
```

Comment: Follow up question, I need to make the array length, the difference between the first day and last day, can i make array.length = lastDay-Firstday / (Convert to days rather than ms)? Does that make sense?

Comment: @MattCarmody I think I understand what you want, I edited my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: its very strange what the professor is asking, or I think so. He wants the actual array length to be the difference? So if the first date is 23/9/2020 and the last day is 29/9/20 the tally array length should be 7  (i called tally array: dateArr)

Comment: @MattCarmody ah so I'm doing your homework? :D haha

Comment: sorry! Haha nono! I just meant, am i able to say, varArr.length = dateDiff? Sorry i dont mean to pass this on! xD Ill work it out

Comment: ah yes i think i understand. sooo 23 to 29 (including 23) is 7 days in total so that would make an array of length 7. let me whip something up and i'll update my anwser

Comment: @MattCarmody added new example. is this what you needed?

Comment: Pretty much I think! But the dates can change depending on what the user inputs! :) So am i able to use Math.Min(dateArr) to get the first date in the array?

Comment: @MattCarmody you can get the first date from the array by doing `dateArr[0]`. 0 being the position of the first item in your array, to get the second you do `dateArr[1]`

Answer (score 0):

3 lines in your javascript code are missing semicolons. My suggestion is to review your code a bit more carefully before posting, and also review the syntax for the various javascript date functions. This should work:

```
const dates = ["28/7/2020", "28/3/2020", "28/1/2020", "28/10/2020"];

var dateArr = [];

var DAY_IN_MS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;


for (i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {

  // format your date string properly for Date()
  var tmp = dates[i].split('/');

  // convert the string to a date
  var d = new Date( tmp[2], tmp[1], tmp[0] );

  console.log( dates[i] );
  console.log( d );

  dateInMs = d.getTime();

  parseInt(dateInMs);

  console.log(dateInMs);

  dateArr.push(dateInMs);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll definitely take that into consideration and will be more careful in future! Thank you for your help :D